# C++ - Namespace vs. Static Functions

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Namespace + functions versus static methods on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class)

I want to group similar functions togther.  I can do it one of two ways.  To me they are just syntactical differences...in the end it does not matter.  Is this view accurate?

Namespace:

```
namespace util
  {
  void print_array(int array[])
    {
    int count = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] );
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) cout << array[i];
    }
  }
```

Class:

```
class Util
  {
  public:
    static void print_array(int array[])
      {
      int count = sizeof(array);
      for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) cout << array[i];
      }
  };
```

Call with

```
Util::print_array()  // Class
```

or

```
util::print_array()  // Namespace
```

Comment: We had this discussion just recently. Hopefully someone will post a link. Namespaces are subject to ADL, while classes are not; classes can be templated, while namespaces cannot.

Answer (score 6):

The second way is silly and a complete nonsense. Classes are not namespaces, and should never be used as such.

Also, the code is wrong, `sizeof(array)` won't return what you think.

Comment: Classes can be templated, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Functions, too. The benefit is partial specialisation, but if you know about that, you're not asking silly questions like this one.

Comment: The "complete nonsense" bit seems overblown: if a compiler will compile it and it has the desired effect, it's sensical by definition. "Silly" is more subjective, but you should still back it up. So, please explain *why* you feel that classes should never be used in the proposed manner.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Functors with all static members? The question is about treating classes as namespaces, and the answer to that is "no, use namespaces". I thought we'd agreed by now that C++ is not Java. (I am tired, though, and could be missing something, but I don't think any concepts advanced than that apply to this question.)

Comment: @Cat:  I agree in principle with you if you are saying "prefer to use namespaces."  But that's not what it *looks* like you're saying.  It looks like you're saying "there is never an instance in which you should use a class as a namespace construct."

Comment: I can think of one reason to use such a `class`, or at least one case where I did because I didn't have another idea.  Specifically, I once had several `class`es entirely defined in a header file.  I wanted them to be able to share some functions, but I didn't want anyone including that header file to gain access to those functions.  My solution was to make the functions `static` and `private` in an otherwise empty class and then make the other classes `friend`s of it.

Answer (score 3):

There are some differences in that the second way allows you to do a couple of (nonsensical) things that the first way does not:

- Using the second way you can create instances of Util using either `Util foo;` or `Util* foo = new Util();`.
- You can also use `Util` as a type parameter for templates (or anywhere else where typenames are allowed). So you could e.g. create a `vector<Util>`.
- You can also calculate the size of Util instances using `sizeof(Util)`.

Since there's no reason you'd want to be able to do either of those things, you should use the first way. Generally you should almost always rethink using a class when there are no circumstances under which you'd want to instantiate it.

On an unrelated note: In your code `sizeof(array)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)` and almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does (i.e. it does **not** tell you how many elements are in the array).