# Private namespace in source files

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a doubt regarding private methods & functions.
Let's say I have some utility methods that needn't be inside a class. But those same methods need to call other ones that I don't want to expose to the user. For example:

**Suspect.h**

```
namespace Suspect {
  /**
  *  \brief This should do this and that and more funny things.
  */
  void VerbalKint(void);  // This is for you to use
}
```

**Suspect.cpp**

```
namespace Suspect {
  namespace Surprise {
    /**
    * \brief The user doesn't need to be aware of this, as long 
    *        the public available VerbalKint does what it should do.
    */
    void KeyserSoze(void) {
      // Whatever
    }
  } // end Surprise

  void VerbalKint(void) {
    Surprise::KeyserSoze();
  }
}
```

So, this layout works. When including the `Suspect.h`, only `VerbalKint` is visible.
This can be as well achieved using a class and marking `VerbalKint` as static:

```
class Suspect {
public:
  // Whatever
  static void VerbalKint(void);
private:
  static void KeyserSoze(void);
};
```

I would like to know if there's any difference between the two approaches. Is one better (faster, easier to maintain) than the other?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You should make `KeyserSoze` `static` in the class too if you want the examples to be equivalent. However, if you put it as a class in a header file, then everyone including that header file can _see_ that there is a function named `KeyserSoze`, so you can't "hide" it.

Comment: For one thing: you can't create a forward declaration of static function without including the class definition.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks. I missed that!

Comment: @AdriC.S. I wonder if your question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class

Comment: Also, if you use an _anonymous_ namespace in the source file, you're effectively disallow the functions in it from being exported. As it is now, if someone makes a prototype of `KeyserSoze` with the correct namespace prefixes, then they can use it, if it's in an anonymous they can not.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's interesting. Thanks.

Comment: `Suspect` should be a class if it should be an object type, or a namespace if it should not be an object type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the functions are 'free', you should use an anonymous namespace in the `*.cpp`:

```
namespace Suspect {
namespace Surprise {
namespace {
    void KeyserSoze(void) {
      // Whatever
    }
} // end anon
} // end Surprise
} // end Suspect
```

or even:

```
namespace {
    void KeyserSoze(void) {
      // Whatever
    }
} // end anon
```

This keeps it away from clients so they cannot access, depend on, or collide with your exports when linking. It also keeps unnecessary declarations from them, reducing their compile times and potentially link times or binary sizes if definitions are visible. Finally, it makes it private so they cannot depend on it and you do not need to maintain it for their use. You can still pass these to the outside world, if you choose (function pointer in `KeyserSoze()`'s case).

At other times, it is preferable to declare a private member function in your class then define it in the `*.cpp` (where possible). Typically, you would opt for this approach when you need a closer relationship with the class (e.g. when you need access to some members). You said this was not the case in the question, but I'm just reiterating when private members should be used.

Comment: This is the most complete answer and covers some topics I had in mind, so accepted!

Comment: Ancient thread, I know....
Should you place the function prototype in the header file inside an anonymous namespace as well?

Comment: @RobertM. Yes. You should place the declaration inside an anonymous namespace block just like the definition.

Answer (score 10):

The best approach is to define all helper functions in an unnamed namespace in `Suspect.cpp`, instead of in the `Suspect::Surprise` namespace.

In your case, this would be:

```
namespace{
void KeyserSoze(){ ... };
}
```

You can simply call `KeyserSoze` without any namespace specifiers from within `Suspect.cpp`.

You can find more information about that here: [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)

Another alternative is to declare `KeyserSoze` to be `static`, but this is not advised by the standard. The C++ Standard reads in section 7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces, paragraph 2:

> The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope, the unnamed-namespace provides a superior alternative

Comment: `static` has been undeprecated in C++11.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, even though the function is not visible to the eye when you do not declare it in any header; it still is available to the user should they write the declaration.

In C++, the mechanism to hide symbols declared at file level is:

- `static` for (global) variables and functions
- `namespace { ... }` (anonymous namespaces) for anything you wish (more general, more verbose)

For example:

```
// Suspect.cpp

namespace Suspect {

    static void KeyserSore() {}

    void VerbalKing() { KeyserSore(); }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between putting something in a class or a namespace is that you can't add extra static functions to a class in another header file.

This:
a.h

```
namespace Fred {
   void Somefunc();
}
```

b.h

```
namespace Fred {
   void Anotherfunc();
}
```

work, although neither a nor b know what each other has done to their namespaces. This could conceivably cause problems, such as this:

c.h

```
namespace Fred {
   void Thirdfunc();
}
```

d.h

```
namespace Fred {
   bool Thirdfunc();
}
```

which is all fine and dandy until you get to run the program...

This is, whilst not impossible, a lot less likely with classes.

In your example, with only one source file, you might also want to consider using the anonymous namespace as that restricts declarations to file scope, so people outside your file can't access them (or clash with them) by accident.

Comment: Thanks for stating the problem that could arise when modifying the namespace in different files.