# is it a good idea if I put all functions as a static methods of class?

Tags: c#, c++

I have some function that are utility function and they are placed inside the namespace as functions.

Having some experience in C#, I know it is not possible to create such function and you need collect all of them inside a class and define them as static.

is it a good idea to do the same here? Creating a class and put all related functions static method of such class? Is there any speed difference?

saw that thread, but there is a big mistake on that answer: I am using classes that has static methods and no other type of method or state. So there is no chance that a static method uses internal data of the class.

All modern OO language such as C# and java doesn't allow you to put a method on a namespace by itself, so there should be a good reason for it. I think the reason is clear: in an OO system, we have class, no function.

C++ born from C and hence we can create functions inside the namespace, but we Should Not Do That!

Comment: No speed difference. Good idea - depending on your SW design scheme.

Comment: Of course, in C++ you *can* put free functions inside a namespace.

Comment: I think this is a very effective way to prevent misuse of `using namespace` (at a global level in a header) which many developers do without understanding the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

There is no speed difference at all. In general, in C++ your current solution is a considered a better coding practice. See for instance this thread for more details: [Namespace + functions versus static methods on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class)

Comment: I saw that thread, but there is a big mistake on that answer: I am using classes that has static methods and no other type of method or state. So there is no chance that a static method uses internal data of the class.