# Why is std::make_shared<T> not a static function of std::shared_ptr<T>, i.e. std::shared_ptr<T>::make?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, language-design

This is a question about understanding a design decision, not a complaint about bugs or flaws.

In the C++ standard library, the function to create a shared pointer and its object is a straight function,

```
template< class T, class... Args> std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

Why is this function not a `static` function of `shared_ptr<T>`, like this:

```
template <class... Args> std::shared_ptr<T>::make(Args&&... args);
```

This would keep the `std::` namespace a little tidier, and would also allow for something like this:

```
using shared_vector = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>;

shared_vector a = shared_vector::make(7);
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only rationale given in the proposal for `std::make_shared`, document [N2351](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm), is that it makes it possible to add the functionality non-intrusively to any already existing implementation of `shared_ptr`.

`std::make_shared` was added to the standard draft after `std::shared_ptr` itself and there had been prior `shared_ptr` implementations, e.g. in boost.